# How practical would this JWT Implementation be?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

Disclaimer, I'm new to JWT's so if any of this makes no sense at all, you now know why lol.

**Motivation**
The security problem this implementation is trying to solve can be summed up by this scenario:

Legit user logs in into the website using a public computer and leaves the place forgetting     to logout, attacker sits at that computer, copy pastes token and uses it whenever he likes  later when he gets home, (because it will always be valid until the secret changes or if        you’re storing token in db until user changes some payload info [what if user never updates     info] then token is forever valid).

**Authentication flow to sort problems mentioned above**

```
1.   Client logs in
      1.1  Verify login details, and if valid:
      1.2  Create token using user id, global secret and expiry date
      1.3  Store token in Database
      1.4  Send token to client
2.   Client stores token [your choice where u wanna store it]
3.   When client sends a request to an authenticated route, use authentication middleware to do the following checks
      3.1  Verify token hasn’t been tampered with
      3.1.1  If not tampered, go to 3.2
      3.1.2  If tampered, redirect to /login
      3.2  check if expiration date is less than current date
      3.2.1  if not less, let user through to the requested route, by calling next()
      3.2.2  if less, check in database if expired token matches the token stored in database
        (to verify if it’s the latest expired token, or not)
        3.2.2.1 if doesn’t match, redirect to /login
        3.2.2.2 If matches
            3.2.2.2.1 create token with renewed expiration date
            3.2.2.2.2 store token in database
            3.2.2.2.3 send token to client
```

**Security drawback of above implementation**
In the case where an attacker got access to a token, and is the one that makes the first request post-token-expiration to get a new token, then this would invalidate the legit user when they tried to get new token and log them out as their token wouldn’t match the one stored in database. Now only the attacker would have same token as the one stored in the database.

**Ways to mitigate this**
Invalidate via login or logout: Generate new token on login / delete token on logout, overwriting the old one in db, this would make all previously issued tokens invalid as soon as they expire. i.e. next time attacker would try to get new token on expiration, it wouldn’t match one in db so they would get rejected forever using that token.

**Usability problems**
Logging in or logging out would invalidate token on all other devices, so you would have to re-login on those devices.

**Possible work around**
Have simple request header check for device type and store different token for each device on login and logout. Then have different db queries based on if statement of the different devices when tokens needs to be refreshed, so u know which one to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.3  Store token in Database

**Not necessary and not recommended**. Verify signature of JWT is the proof that a JWT is valid. Saving tokens requires unnecessary storage space and database access in each request

> Legit user logs in into the website using a public computer and leaves the place forgetting to logout, attacker sits at that computer, copy pastes token and uses it whenever he likes later when he gets home.

This security problem is possible but considers that the risk of attack is low and the number of affected users will not be high because it requires physical access to the shared computer after using your website. Prevention and mitigation measures should be commensurate with the seriousness of the problem.

**You have proposed to invalidate old tokens on a new login/logout of the real user, but the user did not logout, so it does not mitigate the risk.** The server do not know if the token comes from the real user or from the attacker. Possesion of JWT is the proof-of-authentication.

I suggest the following prevention actions:

- **short expiration time**: renew the token every 3-5 minutes
- Use **session storage** instead of cookies/localStorage: Session storage is cleared when the browser closes.

If this actions are not enough for you, then consider to request the credentials for login instead of storing the JWT.

The rest of your points are based on storing JWT in database. As I commented above this does not make sense using JWT

> Usability problems Logging in or logging out would invalidate token on all other devices, so you would have to re-login on those devices.

Issue a new token for each device. It is recommended to let the token expire, but if you need to invalidate a token, you could use a blacklist including a unique identifier `jti` in the JWT.

Comment: Instead of login/logout should've said, login which mitigates the risk by invalidating all previously issued tokens in that they can't be used to get a fresh token no more. Session storage not user friendly as it means that users would have to re-login. Could you please elaborate on how short expiration time would prevent the suggested scenario? If attacker had access to latest token their token would just get refreshed forever anyways, until the real user logs in and invalidates it, or if global secret changes? Thanks for taking the time to explain it though.

Comment: Invalidating old tokens after a new login  means that the attacker will not be able to continue using the stolen token. Mitigates the problem but does not avoid it. And has the side effect that your system can only be used on one device at a time. Alternatively you could add a device identifier or IP to the token, but also has its own drawbacks

Comment: A short expiration time prevents (but does not avoid) the token from being stolen by reducing the time it is exposed. The probability is lower because the attacker only has a few seconds to enter the shared computer, copy and paste. I agree that session storage is not user friendly. Value the risk / benefit of your security measures because you will never get a 100% secure system

Comment: Why does the attacker only have a few seconds to enter shared computer? Even if the token is long expired, as long as the real account owner doesn't re-login, wouldn't the application just send the attacker a fresh token? To me it seems like the attackers window for exploitation is only bounded by the amount of time it takes legit user to re-login?

Comment: Server set an expiration time in the token ( `exp` claim). For example 2 min and App renews token automatically every 1:45 using old token. **After exp time, the server will reject any request**. So attacker just have as much  2' to stole the token. Assuming user has to close browser, machine, etc, the real window is smaller

Comment: How does the app renew the token every set amount of minutes? What if the user doesn't make any requests for those 2minutes, what happens then? Would they not jut get logged out if they made a request couple seconds later after those 2minutes and have to re-login again?

Comment: With a timer that launch and automatic refresh if no request has been done in that period and application is still open. It is an alternative ( sorry, i thought that I have explained it).

Comment: Would this not mean that if u were using the app at home and u closed ur app and opened it again 2min later, u would have to re-login?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Reducing expiration time with this technique increases security, but usability is worst. Storing a long-lived token allows to login after closing, but might be copied in a shared computer. There is no a magic solution for all systems, so consider the most suitable for your use cases. In my opinion the risk of a stolen token is low, so I would prefer to optimize usability

Comment: So if you were to build a simple app that only has user info and a link to their social media, implemented with react and node as a SPA with 1 server serving react app and acting as proxy to 2nd server which would be the api server, (reason behind separate api server is incase i make a native mobile app later) what level of authentication do you think would be enough? Sorry if it sounds stupid I'm a beginner in authentication trying to figure out the best solution without doing something stupid

Comment: Your question makes sense. I would look for usability by extending JWT's life using the previous one and would not give too much importance to a user leaving the session open on a public computer. The possibility that a token is stolen is very low and in the end the responsible is the user.

Comment: By, "I would look for usability by extending JWT's life using the previous one" do you mean once a token expires you would give the same token back but with longer expiration date? No database involved at all? If so what's the point of adding expiration to it at all, isn't it the same as always using the same token, because only source of validity of this authentication would just be the server checking if the token hasn't been tampered with? So even if token was expired, server would just if it hasn't been tampered with and just issue a new one?

Comment: 1) An expired token must be rejected always and user should be redirected to login form. 2) A database for tokens it is not needed 3) Issuing a new JWT with the old one (not expired) is similar to not setting an expiration time but not the same. If the webapp is not used then the token is not renewed and expires.

Comment: But then how is this good for usability if you're forcing user to re-login every time token expires? So if u had 5min expiry time and user didn't click on anything those 5min they would be forced to re-login

Comment: With such a short time would be necessary a timer to automatically refresh if token is close to expire, as I commented above. If you want to keep user connected during large inactivity periods, say 2-3 days, then use a larger expiration time (or not set exp time)

Comment: I just want something like facebook or instagram or twitter where u always stay logged-in they never log u out unless u log out your self

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Do not set expiration time and do not renew tokens.

Comment: Is that what they do and it's acceptable for them security wise?

Comment: I can't say all they do. Google for example adds many extra security measures, checks IP & browser you frecuently use and has mobile phone and alternative email account for security warnings. But if you leave the account open in a shared computer, others can see your email. On the other hand, online banking expires your session when you close browser. Needs and risks are different

Comment: Maybe adding something like remember me underneath login, and then depending on that - save token in localStorage vs sessionStorage. Or another way, instead of above, issue token with expiration when user doesn't select remember me, and issue token without expiration when user selects remember me? Would this be practical in your opinion?

Comment: Both of them seems ok. "Remember me" suggests that if the user leaves the browser it should not be remembered, so the first one seems more appropriate

Comment: Ok, I'm a lot more clearer on all of this now, thanks for taking the time to discuss this with me.

Comment: Happy to help.!

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks quite alright, although pedrofb commensta are valid. However consider the option not to store the JWT itself in the DB, but a refresh token instead. The refresh token is not a JWT, it's just a random number, time-stamp or similar, and the refresh token is embedded in the JWT.

Also consider to add a soft expiry on the JWT. The soft expiry is your proprietary expiry. The JWT is valid for as long as the standard expiry date is not passed, but after the soft expiry you would like to validate the refresh-token in the JWT to the once you stored in your DB. That would be the heart beat of how often to actually validate a user to the DB. The standars expiry date on the other hand would be the date where the user needs to interact with your BE at least once in order to issue a new JWT (with a new expiry date). So maybe the expiry date is like 3 months and soft expiry in 5 minutes.

If the user loggs out, changes PW och if you detect odd behaviour, you can invalidate the refresh token in the DB. You can also change your refresh token each time a new JWT is issues to prevent old JWT's to be renewed. Also, you can store a separate refresh token for each device where the user loggs in, just like you planned for your original proposal. (This allow users to log out from individual devide, monitor from what deviced the user is logged in and to log out from a device remotely.)